# Signed APK does not show Google Maps background

Tags: android, api, key, apk, signed

I'm having trouble displaying Google Maps in my application.

1. I created a certificate and a key to sign the application.
2. With this certificate, I created a Google Maps API key (v1).
3. I put this key on my `mapView` in my XML.
4. When I launch in debug mode (with Eclipse), my application with this API key, and I see the Google Maps background.
5. When I sign my APK using the ADT in Eclipse (pointing my keystore, then my key) and then install this APK on my phone, the background does not show.

I tried to read the logcat, and the only meaningful log was this:

```
12-09 18:19:18.247: W/System.err(9968): IOException processing: 26
12-09 18:19:18.247: W/System.err(9968): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
12-09 18:19:18.247: W/System.err(9968):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
12-09 18:19:18.247: W/System.err(9968):     at         android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
12-09 18:19:18.247: W/System.err(9968):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
12-09 18:19:18.247: W/System.err(9968):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
```

Which didn't help me very much...

Comment: There are two keys provided by Google, one for debugging and the other one for release. Are you sure you signed with the right one>

Comment: I only see one key when I entered my certificate MD5 fingerprint in here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup

Comment: It is mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html). Look again.

Comment: I followed this. I signed my application using the ADT plugin of Eclipse. I used my keystore in the dropdown list and my key too. With this same keystore I get the Gmap API key.